# Как средствами css сделать высоту textarea по содержимому

Tags: html, css

Как средствами css сделать блок textarea во всю высоту по содержимому?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Вас [сюда][1] или [сюда][2]. В конце концов, если без всяких "плюшек и рюшек", то [можно сделать так][3].

   [1]:http://jquerylist.ru/forms/jquery-plugin-autoresize.html
   [2]:http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/
   [3]:http://jsfiddle.net/w6S76/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне нужно было выводить многострочные тексты result, первой строкой которых является заголовок. Понравился эффект от

```
let newData = `<textarea contenteditable="true" rows="1">${result}</textarea>`;
```

Текстовое поле по высоте соответствует количеству строк, а первая строка (заголовок) оказывается в рамке

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае советую вместо textarea использовать:

```html
  <div contenteditable="true">
    Я редактируюсь!
  </div>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не добавляет ничего нового в уже выданные ответы, кроме того, что вы "приводите полный фрагмент кода" (весьма банальный). Я рекомендую сосредоточиться на вопросах, которые в настоящий момент неотвечены. Здесь же вы и людям не поможете, да и репутации (если вас это сильно интересует) особо не насобираете.

Comment: @AK, а точно ли полный? [Тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988) пополнее будет...

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, никак.

Используй `div` с аттрибутом `contenteditable`. Только он не будет чатью формы и в нём можно форматировать текст.

Подробнее про вариант с contenteditable в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988).

Comment: @Jony, ответ обновлён.

Answer (score 1):

можно абсолютным позиционированием например.

```
{
top:10px;
bottom:10px;
position:absolute;
}
```

вот и растянет тебе.

или js юзать

Comment: Это не по содержимому.

Comment: А если с JS, но без сторонних библиотек, то насколько просто это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
.textarea{
  display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
textarea {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/7AwXb/1/)