# Как сделать авто размер высоты textarea?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать авто размер высоты `textarea`? Как сделать без плагин и красиво?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под авторазмером? Заполнение высоты блока на 100% или же авторасширение?

Comment: @Cyrus Авто изменение высоты textarea при вводе текста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без JavaScript невозможно. Возьмите вот:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Comment: Спасибо но мне нужно без плагинов

Comment: Ну вот возьмите сам код: https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/blob/master/dist/autosize.js

что вам еще нужно? Чтобы вам тот же код написали тут?

Comment: Эта задача не имеет столь простого решения.

Comment: Аааа я понял спасибо!!!

Answer (score 7):

А использовать contenteditable не годится?

```css
.editor {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .2em;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}

.editor:empty:after {
  content: "";
}

.editor * {
  all: inherit !important;
  /* Для тех, кто не умеет all (вероятно, надо дополнить) */
  color: inherit !important;
  background: none !important;
  white-space: pre !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
  /* Переопределение .editor */
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  resize: none !important;
  display: inline !important;
}

.editor div {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable class=editor></div>
```

Comment: @KYRAN, ответ обновлён. Исправлены косяки со свойством display. Но на кроссбраузерность это в любом случае надо очень внимательно проверять.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/217579) верен, но вместо `white-space: pre` нужно использовать `white-space: pre-wrap`, иначе с динамической шириной текст выйдет за пределы блока.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тук-тук вас упомянули.

Comment: @0xdb, ну да, у меня не переносится и рамка выходит прикольная)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Хмм, 1 мар в 12:08, только сейчас это стало известно? Так получаеется Maria права?

Comment: @0xdb, только сейчас кто-то поставил плюс на мой ответ, поэтому я увидел соседний. Она не совсем права, потому что для разрыва длинных слов понадобится ещё дополнительно другое свойство, но такой вариант тоже возможен. Вообще, всё зависит от того, что требуется получить.