# Изменить цвет части текста в <textarea>

Tags: html, css

Как изменить часть текста в `<textarea>`.

```
<textarea>Этот текст красный, этот текст зелёный, а этот уже синий.</textarea>
```

Comment: может так? http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/y99rmbhy/

Comment: @soledar10, зачем тебе jQuery вместо написания одного атрибута в разметке?

Comment: @Qwertiy - да скорее всего лучше добавить атрибут contenteditable, но это личное дело каждого, что и как использовать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не уверен, что можно форматировать текст внутри стандартного HTML `<textarea>`. Даже, пожалуй, готов утверждать, что это не возможно.

Однако можно обмануть код.
Создайте `<div>` с аттрибутом `contenteditable`. Что-то типа такого:

```
<div id='tweakTheCode' contenteditable></div>
```

Вот рабочий вариант:

```html
<div id='tweakTheCode_editable' contenteditable>Этот <span style="color: red;">текст красный</span>, этот <span style="color: green;">текст зелёный</span>, а этот <span style="color: blue;">уже синий</span>.</div>  
<div id='tweakTheCode_not_editable'>this text is not editable</div>
```

Однако не забудьте, что это всего лишь `div`, так что для использования обновленного содержимого понадобится дополнительный `js`.
Разумнее всего продублировать `<div>` реальным `<textarea>` и перед отсылкой формы переносить содержимое из `<div>` в `<textarea>`.
Типа такого:

```
$('#tweakTheCode_textarea').val($('#tweakTheCode_editable').html());
```

Comment: Как защититься от вставки форматированной разметки?

Comment: @Qwertiy ха! хороший вопрос... но тут все зависит от проекта и желания программиста :) но по идее, надо анализировать/чистить содержимое `<div>` перед переносом в привязанную `<textarea>`

Comment: Я имел в виду визуально для пользователя. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988 - этот вариант же не подойдёт (тем более, кроссбраузерностью `all` не блещет)...