# Редактирование содержимого ячейки при двойном нажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как мне сделать, что бы когда я нажал два раза на ячейку таблицы, то включалась возможность её редактировать и так же в обратном порядке.

Я сделал таблицу, а как сделать, что бы она редактировалась - не знаю.

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для двойного нажатие есть событие `dblclick`. А редактирование включать можно через атрибут `contenteditable`:

```js
$('#my_table td').dblclick(function() {
  if( $(this).attr('contenteditable') !== undefined ){
    $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
  }else{
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', '');
  };
});
```

```css
#my_table td[contenteditable] {background-color: black; color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" id="my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Благодарю, милейший :3

Comment: @Yuri надо еще добавить стили, как в этом ответе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454186/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-textarea/454198#454198