# Мониторинг html формы через JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Решил добавить смайлики на сайт по вот этому примеру https://myrusakov.ru/php-comments-smile.html
есть панель смайликов (каждый смайлк это ссылка с методом onclick(); и изображением смайлика) в методе onclick() стоит функция автоматической вставки кода смайлика в форму. Проверка на наличие в сообщении пользователя кодов смайликов происходит перед записью в базу, тоесть в базе они уже преобразованы в ссилки на иконку (картинку) смайлика, по этому при выводе они уже оображаются.
Но возникла проблема, при роботе метода onclick() (функции вставки кода смайлика в форму) в самой форме во время редактирования в форме стоит код смайлика а не его изображение!

Теперь вопрос, как сделать чтобы при вводе (или встевке через onclick()...) в форму кода смайлика, он сразуже менялся на соответствующее изображение...
Типо как в ВК нажал на смайлик и в форме именно смайлик а не его код...
Может заменять коды слайликов на изображения еще до отправки????
Если да то как?

Код функции вставки смайлика:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function set(){
 document.getElementById('m').value+='';
 document.getElementById('m').focus();}
 </script>
```

Код формы:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <label>Massage:</label>
 <a href="" onclick="set(); return false;">
 <img src="smiles/smile01.png"  height="40" width="40" id="img"/>
 </a>
 <input type="text" name="massage" id="m" required="required"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

Comment: Если вы добавите код, то легче будет ответить  на ваш вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988

Answer (score 2):

В `input` и `textarea` невозможно вставить `html`.
В ВК, если внимательно изучить, то поля ввода сообщений/новостей реализовано `div`'ами с обработчиками ввода текста с клавиатуры. Вот в `div`'ах `html` теги (смайлики в том числе) уже и отображаются.

Comment: Cheg, а можно по подробнее...

Comment: Нужны примеры кода...

Comment: Привел пример кода

Comment: @Duoxx Duoxx эта форма роботает но она не отправляется... Как в оброботчике получить даные из div а

Comment: парсить сурсы имджа