# Динамический размер input/textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

такой вопрос, как сделать, чтобы при вводе или выводе текста при помощи input или чего-либо еще:

---

1. Зафиксировать ширину инпута (это я сделал);
2. Высоту сделать динамической, чтобы она увеличивалась в зависимости от размера?

---

Вот у меня к примеру есть input.

```
<input type="text" class ="tcal" size="60" name ="CheckSC" value="$CheckSC"/>
```

Читал про textarea, но там высоту надо заранее задавать количество строк, но количество строк заранее неизвестно.

Спасибо за внимание=)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height

Comment: Перенос текста может быть только в textarea, обычные input так не умеют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для моих целей подойдет один из методов, располагающийся по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height.
Решил его вынести сюда, т.к. в русской версии stackoverflow, подобного я не нашел, думаю это поможет кому-либо еще=)

```
function auto_grow(element) {
element.style.height = "5px";
element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}

textarea {
resize: none;
overflow: hidden;
min-height: 50px;
max-height: 100px;
}

<textarea oninput="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать div

```html
<div contenteditable="true">test</div>
```

Comment: Вот, я читал об этом, но нигде не нашел, как отправить форму из редактируемого дива?

Comment: @findley Сейчас дополню

Comment: Так легко не выёдет - он же для форматированного текста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988

Answer (score 0):

Писать в несколько строк в input нельзя, поэтому можно только динамически менять ширину input следующим образом
`<input type="text" onkeydown="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">`